# Nome dinâmico de componente Delphi

Tags: delphi

Em jQuery conseguimos fazer referencia a um elemento da forma abaixo:

```
var tipo = "B";
$("#campoTipo"+tipo).val("Teste");
```

que seria o mesmo que:

```
$("#campoTipoB").val("Teste");
```

Preciso em Delphi, desabilitar alguns botões que dependem de uma Query

```
procedure TFormCupom.BitBtn3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
ponteiro: Integer;
painel: TPanel;  
begin
 DM.FDConexao.Connected := true;
 ponteiro := 0;
 with DM.FDQ_Recentes do
 begin
  close;
  sql.clear;
  sql.add('SELECT * FROM rotativo');
  open;
  First; // primeiro
  while not eof do
   begin
   inc(ponteiro);
   painel := FindComponent('Pn' + IntToStr(ponteiro)) as TPanel;
    if painel <> nil then
      painel.Visible := false;
      Next; // proximo
    end;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Não consegui entender o porque da consulta ao banco de dados. O código não utiliza nenhum dado da query. Para saber porque o código não está funcionando é preciso saber como os TPanel foram criados e nomeados. O FindComponent retornará a referência ao Panel apenas se for o Owner do mesmo, e se Panel.Name estiver corretamente especificado.

Comment: Ricardo, os Panel são criados em tempo de design e ficam invisíveis. De acordo com a query eles ficarão visíveis ou não.

Comment: O nome de cada TPanel foi atribuído no Object Inspector (Pn1, Pn2, ...)? Quantos Panels há no form?

Comment: Sim. No Object Inspetor. Há vários mas os que preciso manipular são 7. Pn1... Pn7

Comment: Ok. E o que vc lê da query para determinar qual panel será ativado?

Comment: Na verdade a cada laço ativará o Panel correspondente. Ex. var ponteiro = 1 Pn1 fica visível. Eu usarei os dados dos campos para popular Label's que tem dentro dos Panel.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66362/discussion-between-ricardo-alves-carvalho-and-ezequiel-tavares).

Comment: Tentei usar o chat, mas não consegui. Eu fiz um teste assim e funcionou:procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  panel: TPanel;
  ponteiro: integer;
begin
  for ponteiro := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    panel := FindComponent('Pn' + IntToStr(ponteiro)) as TPanel;
    if Assigned(panel) then
      panel.Visible := True;
  end;
end;

Comment: Assim que chegar em casa testo e volto aqui

Answer (score 1):

Assim você consegue pegar o elemento utilizando uma string, como no jquery:

```
var 
painel: TPanel;
painel := FindComponent('Pn' + IntToStr(ponteiro)) as TPanel;
if painel <> nil then  
    painel.Visible := not painel.Visible;
```

Comment: Deu um Exception

Comment: Você esta testando? É para conferir o código? Se o elemento que você quer pegar for um TPanel acredito que vá funcionar, para você fazer os teste de forma mais efetiva, coloque uma string de forma manual para pegar apenas 1 elemento, assim você já descarta qualquer outro problema que possa acontecer no while.

Comment: Exatamente é TPanel, estou testando para desabilitar e mesmo colocando manualmente da o erro.

Comment: Qual é a Exception?

Comment: Exception class $C0000005 with message 'c0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION'.

Comment: Fiz uma alteração na resposta utilizando painel, olhe se vai funcionar desta forma.

Comment: Agora não dá a exceção mas nao deixa invisivel o Panel

Comment: Se você trocar not painel.Visible; por False, volta a exceção?

Comment: troquei e nao voltou a exceção.

Comment: Mas depois da alteração, funcionou?

Comment: Não desabilitou os Panel e não deu a exceção

Comment: Ele não esta entrando no 'if painel <> nil then', consequentemente ele não esta encontrando o elemento, e a variável painel esta nula, verifique se o nome é realmente 'Fn' alguma coisa do painel.

Comment: Os nomes são Pn1, Pn2, ... Pn7 . Estava olhando aqui, eles estão dentro de outro Panel, sera que tem algo a ver?

Comment: Eu acredito que não vá fazer diferença estando em outro painel, até porque o FindComponent simplesmente pega o elemento usando uma string, já vi esta forma de usar também TPanel(FindComponent('Pn' + IntToStr(ponteiro)), mas quando vi a pessoa esta criando o elemento, eu não estou entendo porque ele não esta conseguindo pegar, o FindComponent faz parte do TComponent que provavelmente já foi importado, já que você utiliza outros elementos.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com o codigo que tenho até o momento.

Comment: Tenta só mais uma coisinha, estava lendo aqui tenta desta forma: painelExterno.FindComponent(...

Comment: painel := Panel2.FindComponent('Pn' + IntToStr(ponteiro)) as TPanel;             nada feito

Comment: Como esse panel é criado? Ex: panel := TPanel.Create(Self) / TPanel.Create(nil) / TPanel.Create(Application) ???

Comment: Ele é inserido em tempo de design. E ficará visível dinamicamente

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um teste com esse código e funcionou:

`procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  panel: TPanel;
  ponteiro: integer;
begin
  for ponteiro := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    panel := FindComponent('Pn' + IntToStr(ponteiro)) as TPanel;
    if Assigned(panel) then
      panel.Visible := True;
  end;
end;`

Um possível problema seria se os panels não tivessem a propriedade name setadas como esperado (diferente da propriedade caption).